# django, "is not JSON serializable" when using ugettext_lazy?

Tags: python, django, json

I have this in my `views.py`

```
response_dict = {
    'status': status,
    'message': message
}
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict),
                    mimetype='application/javascript')
```

Since I start using this import:

`from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`

at this line:

`message = _('This is a test message')`

I get this error:

```
 File "/home/chris/work/project/prokject/main/views.py", line 830, in fooFunc
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict),

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

TypeError: <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7f42d581b590> is not JSON serializable
```

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not strings anymore, but django.utils.functional.__proxy__ objects ;) try calling unicode with them.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can also create you own JSON encoder that will force `__proxy__` to unicode.

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/

```
from django.utils.functional import Promise
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

class LazyEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Promise):
            return force_text(obj)
        return super(LazyEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

So now your code can look like:

```
response_dict = {
    'status': status,
    'message': _('Your message')
}

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_dict, cls=LazyEncoder),
                    mimetype='application/javascript')
```

Answer (score 24):

It's not a string yet, and Python's JSON encoder doesn't know about ugettext_lazy, so you'll have to force it to become a string with something like

```
response_dict = {
    'status': status,
    'message': unicode(message)
}
```

Comment: What would you do if you were using Python3?

Comment: I haven't used Django with Python 3 yet, but `string()` instead of unicode should do the exact same thing.

Comment: you mean `str()`

Answer (score 0):

You can custom `JSONEncoder` or use `str` as `default` serialize method:

```
# Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2022/3/28
import json
from json import JSONEncoder
from typing import Any

import django
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

settings.configure()
django.setup()


class MyEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o: Any) -> Any:
        if getattr(type(o), "_delegate_text", False):
            return str(o)
        return super().default(o)


print(json.dumps(dict(hello=_("world")), default=str))
print(json.dumps(dict(hello=_("world")), cls=MyEncoder))
```